# What would be an appropriate collection type for storing few elements?

Tags: scala, collections, enums

Of the different collection types supported in Scala (lists, maps, hashmaps, set etc) what would be an appropriate collection type for implementing something that can be done by C code below

```
typedef enum { GOOD BAD MAX_QUALITY } quality

struct student_data s_data[MAX_QUALITY];
```

The collection size is small... 2 or 3 elements, but having a collection helps to keep the code elegant, when performing similar operations on the data .

Thanks!

Comment: For more info on choosing the proper collection I'd recommend Josh Seureth's book [Scala in Depth](http://www.amazon.com/Scala-Depth-Joshua-Suereth-D/dp/1935182706) which has a chapter titled "Using the right collection" which addresses the various use cases and trade offs for each collection type.

Answer (score 2):

`List` or `Seq` of different `case classes` should do the trick.  When I say different case classes, I really mean:

```
case class CaseClass1(arg1: String, arg2: Int, arg3: OtherCaseClass)
case class OtherCaseClass(arg1: String, arg2: String)

val foo: List[CaseClass1] = ...
```

Then instances of `CaseClass1` are composed and stored in your list.

Comment: Do not forget about [Enums](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Enumeration.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to create an enum-like data structure which provides a fast index lookup, I would go for:

```
sealed trait Quality { val index: Int }
case class BAD() extends Quality { val index = 0 } 
case class GOOD() extends Quality { val index = 1 } 
case class MAX_QUALITY() extends Quality { val index = 2 }
```

This allows to use pattern matching on an arbitrary `quality: Quality` and the verbose syntax `quality.index` makes it explicit that quality is used as an `Int` index at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate further ?
If your intention is to create structure in which you associate to something of type `quality` a data structure of type `student_data` then you can use a Map

Depending on whether you need mutable access, or you just create the structure and then the access is read-only you would use mutable or immutable maps.

I suggest, in your case, to use immutable Maps. The Scala Collection Library provides specialized versions for small maps, up to 5 inserted key-value pairs, which provide better performance and memory footprint than the unspecialized types of map.

```
val x = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 3)
println(x.getClass)
>> class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2
```

You can also define an alias, to work more easily with your structures

```
type StudentStruct = Map[Quality, StudentData]
```

Usage:

```
val studentStruct = Map(Bad -> studentData)
val studentStruct2 = studentStruct + (Good -> studentData2)
```

Hope it helps.